# symfony2: overriding block title is not working

Tags: php, symfony

In my base layout page:

```
<title>{% block title %} main title {% endblock %}</title>
```

In my template page :

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %} child title {% endblock %}
```

Yet, the title is not changed to 'child title'. Other blocks (like body or scripts) are working perfectly fine. What's wrong with the code above?

** [EDIT] **

However doing the following works :

child layout:

```
{% block head %}
<title>child title</title>
{% endblock %}
```

master layout:

```
<head>
    {% block head %} {% endblock %}
 </head
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are extending the document you think you are extending?

Comment: do you maybe render the base.html.twig and not the child.html.twig file?

Comment: yes, I'm sure i'm using the right files. I've edited my post - see update

Comment: try defining the full namespace for base.html.twig. Also try changing the block "title" to a different name (e.g. title2 or something) to see if thats the issue.